# Weird 'rainbow' background effect on input fields filled with sequences of characters

Tags: css, forms, text, fonts, colors

Today I have rather funny issue, which is not really a problem, but I wanted to know why this happens.

I've got an input field which has css properties as follows:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-user-select: text;
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-bottom-color: rgb(156, 189, 234);
border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(156, 189, 234);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: rgb(156, 189, 234);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-top-color: rgb(156, 189, 234);
border-top-left-radius: 3px;
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
cursor: auto;
display: block;
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
height: 37px;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: normal;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-left: 14px;
padding-right: 14px;
padding-top: 10px;
text-align: start;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
width: 365.875px;
word-spacing: 0px;
writing-mode: lr-tb;
```

If I fill the input field with the sequence of 'narrow' (eg. i or j) characters I get this cool effect:

[image: rainbow!]

If I fill it with wider characters it acts as expected:

[image: normal text]

I've figured out that if I turn off font-family property (in dev tools) the text behaves normal again. If I change the text color or background-color the rainbow effect stays.

I was able to replicate this issue on Chrome (Linux and Windows) and Firefox (Linux and Windows).

Do you guys have any ideas on how this happens?

Cheers

Comment: Can you provide a working Fiddle please?

Comment: What the hell is with all that CSS for one element? Also its just you [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c8426jb6/), it don't do it in there, other reasons would be software/hardware problems.

Comment: It's all the styles applied by the browser (computed styles in dev tools)

Comment: Google "Sub-pixel rendering"

Comment: I don't have that problem http://i.imgur.com/mTYFGez.jpg